# unxutils zsh on wide terminal

Tags: windows-xp, terminal, zsh

I'm usually working on linux, but am now forced to use windows (xp). In search of a usable shell, I installed unxutils. They provide a zsh and when used with the default setup it works nicely.

But then I wanted to increase the width of the terminal window (cmd.exe or console2). I set it to 150 columns. Now the zsh shows strange characters on the right of every command prompt and gives a beep (probably because there is the bell-character in there).

How can I get the unxutils zsh to work with a wider terminal?

Comment: have you tried [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys)?

Comment: @FelipeLema: No, but it seems I need mwing for that. That seems overkill just for a shell.

Comment: you should then report this problem to the [zsh developers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/mlist.html). I get the feeling they don't maintain strict tests on the windows platform